# How to open form from Child Form and show in main form panel

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, menu

I am currently developing a Windows Form application in C# Visual Studio 2017 and decided to implement a side panel menu using the tutorial [seen here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JP5rgXO_5Sk).

It is great for displaying the child forms when clicked, however I was wondering how I can replace the current child form with a new child form, within the child form code. I.e. how do I access the main form within the child form code.

```
private Form activeForm = null;
    private void openChildForm(Form childForm)
    {
        if (activeForm != null)
            activeForm.Close();
        activeForm = childForm;
        childForm.TopLevel = false;
        childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        childFormPanel.Controls.Add(childForm);
        childFormPanel.Tag = childForm;
        childForm.BringToFront();
        childForm.Show();
    }
```

That is how the child form is opened within the main form. How can I access this method through the child form?
I trust this may be quite confusing but if you have a quick look at the video, you'll understand what I mean.

Thanks!

Comment: Create an event in the Child Form that you can bind to in the main form. When the child requests to be changed, the main form can handle the changing.

Comment: Sounds exactly like what I should be doing, could you point me in the right direction regarding how I can bind the event into the main form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use a static class that retains an instance of your main form. When you main form loads set the MainForm static property in the FormController class. Then from your child forms call the FormControll.openChildForm(...);

```
public static FormController{
    public static Form MainForm {get;set;}
    
    private static Form activeForm = null;
    public static void openChildForm(Form childForm)
    {
       if (activeForm != null)
          activeForm.Close();
       activeForm = childForm;
       MainForm.childForm.TopLevel = false;
       MainForm.childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
       MainForm.childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
       MainForm.childFormPanel.Controls.Add(childForm);
       MainForm.childFormPanel.Tag = childForm;
       MainForm.childForm.BringToFront();
       MainForm.childForm.Show();
     }
}
```

Then in your child forms you can call that static class to change forms.

```
public class ChildForm{
    private void btn_click(...){
        FormController.openChildForm(<newChildForm>);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I hold the activeForm variable?

Comment: In the FormsController. It would be a private static variable that gets checked (and set) within the openChildForm method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use events to handle this:

Step 1) Create a new class that inherits from Form. This will be your base class for all of your children's forms. You can call this ChildForm (inherits from) Form.

Step 2) Define a new public Event that you can bind to from your function of changing the child form.

That could look something like this:

```
public event EventHandler OnRequestChildChange;
```

Step 3) In your child where you want to request a change you can call to this:

OnRequestChildChange?.Invoke(null); //This would pass in your parameters as well, so you could create an event that allows you to pass in custom parameters and pass in the name or type of form, and have a switch statement in your event handler.

Custom Events:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-publish-events-that-conform-to-net-framework-guidelines

Step 4) Bind to the event in your main function

```
private ChildForm activeForm = null;
private void openChildForm(ChildForm childForm)
{
  if (activeForm != null){
    activeForm.OnRequestChildChange -= Child_RequestChange;
    activeForm.Close();
  }

  activeForm = childForm;
  activeForm.OnRequestChildChange += Child_RequestChange;
  childForm.TopLevel = false;
  childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
  childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
  childFormPanel.Controls.Add(childForm);
  childFormPanel.Tag = childForm;
  childForm.BringToFront();
  childForm.Show();
}
```

Step 5) Create the event handler 'Child_RequestChange' which will handle swapping the forms when the child requests by creating a new instance, or pulling a local instance of the new form you want and calling the method above.

Comment: Should all my forms now look like this? `public partial class CabinetForm : ChildForm`

Comment: Yes, they will now reference your base class.

Comment: I tried that however I was then unable to view the forms in designer mode